# How to load an external typescript module that is defined as an internal module (tsd)

Tags: typescript, tsd

I am trying to load the [nouislider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) module in my project: Angular 2 beta-0, Typescript 1.7 using SystemJs 0.19.4.

I have it working with a work-around: by changing the .d.ts file `tsd` has installed for me. I would like to know what, if anything, I can do to load the module without altering the  original typescript definition file: [nouislider.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/nouislider/nouislider.d.ts).

With my changes I can currently load `nouislider` and use it in my Typescript project with SystemJs like so:

```
import {create as createSlider}  from 'noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider';
createSlider(document.getElementById('test-slider'), {
  start: 40,  connect: "lower",
  range: { 'min': 0, 'max': 100 }
});
```

What I did to get it working was change these two lines at the top in `nouislider.d.ts`:

```
declare module noUiSlider {
    function create(target: HTMLElement, options: Options): void;
```

into

```
declare module 'noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider' {
    export function create(target : HTMLElement, options : Options) : void;
```

I set the module's name to 'noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider', otherwise System.js does not load the module from the right path. And I export the create function, since otherwise I have no way of loading it

How can I prevent making these two changes? I would be quite content creating an external module definition myself that references the internal module definition or achieve the same result some other way without changing nouislider.d.ts. I've tried a bunch of things, but couldn't make it work, and seem to be getting lost in all the docs. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No much you can do I am afraid other than creating a pull request on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and propose *adding*

```
declare module 'noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider' {
     export = noUiSlider;
}
```

This should simply add the possibility to use it as an external module without breaking any existing use

Comment: Great I've actually added this linking piece between the external and internal module in a separate file: /// `<reference path="../typings/tsd/nouislider/nouislider.d.ts"/>
declare module 'noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider' {
  export = noUiSlider;
}`. That's all I was looking for. Thanks!